# joda-time неправильно выводит разницу между двумя датами

Tags: java, jodatime

```
DateTime dateTimeS = new DateTime(2017, 4, 3, 0, 0);
DateTime dateTimeE = new DateTime(2017, 4, 11, 0, 0);

Period period = new Period(dateTimeS, dateTimeE);

System.out.println( period.getDays()+
                ":"+period.getMonths()+
                ":"+period.getYears());
```

Разница 8 дней, а показывает только 1 день. Больше 6 дней метод `period.getDays()` показывать не хочет.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59571/discussion-on-question-by--joda-time-----).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться третьим параметром [PeriodType](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html#Period(long,%20long,%20org.joda.time.PeriodType)):

```
private static String backDays(DateTime from, DateTime to) {
    Period period = new Period(from, to, PeriodType.yearMonthDay());
    return period.getDays() + ":" + period.getMonths() + ":" + period.getYears();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTime dateTimeS = new DateTime(2017, 4, 3, 0, 0);
    DateTime dateTimeE = new DateTime(2017, 4, 11, 0, 0);

    System.out.println(backDays(dateTimeS, dateTimeE)); // 8:0:0
}
```

[PeriodType](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/PeriodType.html) задаёт используемые в периоде поля, на которые он делится.

- **Standard**(по умолчанию, все поля) - годы, месяцы(0-30), недели(0-4), дни(0-6), часы(0-23), минуты, секунды, миллисекунды
- **YearMonthDayTime** - годы, месяцы(0-11), дни(0-30), поля времени
- **YearMonthDay** - годы, месяцы(0-11), дни(0-30)
- **YearWeekDayTime** - годы, недели(до года), дни(0-6), поля времени
- **YearWeekDay** - годы, недели(до года), дни(0-6)
- **YearDayTime** - годы, дни(до года), поля времени
- **YearDay** - годы, дни(до года)
- **DayTime** - дни(много), поля времени
- **Time** - поля времени(может быть много часов)
- по одному типу на каждый простой тип
  например, **Seconds** - все секунды в периоде в одном поле

Comment: Спасибо большое)))

Comment: @Мурад Если ответ решил Вашу проблему, [отметьте его как правильный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) (слева от вопроса должна быть галочка)